# Make able to search with number in react Js

Tags: reactjs, search, algolia

Below is my page with query parameter:

```
https://example.com/en/product-search?query=EMS-M8UYT-
```

You can see I am passing an instruction to search product having name: **EMS-M8UYT-** and when I hit for search it actually found product successfully.

What I want is that When I pass any number with my product like If I add 0 next to my search query like this: **EMS-M8UYT-0** It does not shows me any output I wanted to show same product on search when I search with  **EMS-M8UYT-**.

In simple wording: How I can search product If I pass any number with my product name like this: EMS-M8UYT-0-11. (When I search with: EMS-M8UYT-0-11 I got message No results have been found).

Below is my search function:

```
export default function ProductSearch({ settings, searchClient }) {
  // console.log("ResourcesSearch");
  let location = {
    search: "",
  };

  if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
    location = window.location;
  }
  const [searchState, setSearchState] = useState(
    urlToSearchState(location, fields)
  );
  const [showAllFilters, setShowAllFilters] = useState(false);

  const [overlayState, setOverlayState] = useState(urlToOverlayState(location));

  function onSearchStateChange(updatedSearchState) {

    if (
      !isEqual(searchState.query, updatedSearchState.query) ||
      !isEqual(searchState.page, updatedSearchState.page) ||
      !isEqual(searchState.refinementList, updatedSearchState.refinementList) ||
      !isEqual(searchState.range, updatedSearchState.range)
    ) {
      if (path !== "?") {
        navigate(location.pathname + path, {
          state: {
            disableScrollUpdate: true,
          },
        });
        setSearchState(updatedSearchState);
      }
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    setSearchState(urlToSearchState(location, fields));
    setOverlayState(urlToOverlayState(location));
  }, [location]);

  function toggleFilters() {
    setShowAllFilters(!showAllFilters);
  }

  function resetAllFilters() {
  }

  const SearchStats = connectStateResults(({ allSearchResults }) => {
    let nbHits = 0;

    if (allSearchResults) {
      nbHits = allSearchResults.nbHits;
    }

    return (
      <div className="text-defaultBodyText font-bold">
        {nbHits} Products found
      </div>
    );
  });

  const Results = connectStateResults(
    ({ searchState, searchResults, children }) =>
      searchResults && searchResults.nbHits !== 0 ? (
        children
      ) : (
        <div>No results have been found for {searchState.query}.</div>
      )
  );
```